# JavaFX, Having the same object/item in different scenes in the same stage?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scene, stage

I am working on an application in JavaFX where I need multiple scenes to switch between. But it seems like I can't have the same item (Example: a toolbar) In multiple scenes, it just shows the item in one of the scenes. Maybe it isn't possible to have the same item in different scenes, so my question is how do I do it then? Do I need multiple stages and if that is the case how do I change between stages? I am not using FXML for this project, we have to code it.. My current code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Label time;

    private int minute;
    private int hour;
    private int second;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // CLOCK RUNNING

    public void initialize() {

            Timeline clock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                //System.out.println(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);
                time.setText(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);
            }),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
            );
            clock.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            clock.play();
        }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        //Specify The Size of Scenes, and the scenes.
        BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane root2 = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(root1, 1100, 900);
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2,1100,900);


        // Get CSS File
        scene1.getStylesheets().add("Helmuth.css");


        time = new Label("Time:");
        initialize();


        //ToolBar i want this to be shown in both scenes //

        Button homebt = new Button("Home");
        Button tabelbt = new Button("Tabel");


        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
        toolBar.getItems().add(homebt);
        toolBar.getItems().add(tabelbt);
        toolBar.getItems().add(time);


        Label label1 = new Label("Welcome to the first scene!");
        Button button1 = new Button("Go to scene 2");
        button1.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene2));

        VBox layout1 = new VBox();
        layout1.getChildren().addAll(button1,toolBar);

        Button button2 = new Button("Go Back");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene1));

        VBox mainbox = new VBox();
        mainbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        mainbox.getChildren().addAll(button2, toolBar);


        // Start scene 1
        root2.setCenter(mainbox);
        root1.setCenter(layout1);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Helmuth");
        boolean b = false;
        primaryStage.setResizable(b);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Node`s are restricted to at most 1 parent and at most 1 scene. Trying to use it in multiple places either removes it from the old parent or results in an exception. You can replace parts of a scene though, e.g. using `BorderPane.setCenter` or by modifying the child list of some parent, so reusing parts of a scene is not off the table. If you need to show a node in multiple locations/scenes at the same time though, your only option is to create a copy. Using methods to create parts of the scene could reduce code duplication in this case.

Comment: Okay thanks! So it is either duplication of the code, or making methods that can be called in multiple scenes?

Comment: Use this library. It provides a javafx Stage object with additional features : https://github.com/Oshan96/CustomStage   (To change the scene, you just have to do "customStage.changeScene(yourNode);" everything is explained in its readme and wiki : https://github.com/Oshan96/CustomStage/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to switch between different scenes. A solution to your problem might be to just exchange the root node of the scene.

Comment: What do you mean by that, im pretty new at java and javaFX?

Comment: Every scene has a root node and this can be changed. So instead of changing the scene you just set a new root node.